# cannot authenticate in mongodb arbiter

Tags: mongodb

I am currently on mongodb 2.4.8. I have a replicate set on one machine that consists of primary, secondary and an arbiter. I have authenication turned on. My problem is that I cannot log into the arbiter, authenticate and run "db.logRotate();" It keeps failing on permissions. I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong or if this just cannot be done and I have to do a "kill usr1" instead.

Comment: i ran the command suggested by jpsf and i get the following:          > use adminuse admin
switched to db admin
> db.runCommand( { logRotate : 1 } );db.runCommand( { logRotate : 1 } );
{ "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "unauthorized" }

Comment: The "unauthorized" error means you are using authentication and are not logged in as a user with suitable permissions to perform the task on the admin database. Under 2.4 the logRotate command requires the "clusterAdmin" privilege.

Comment: I can rotate the log successfully on both the primary or the secondary. I cannot get this command to work on the arbiter. I cannot authenticate on the arbiter either. The user id i use has the "clusterAdmin" privilege.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Rotate Log Files](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/rotate-log-files/#forcing-a-log-rotation-with-sigusr1) you can rotate log files with `kill -SIGUSR1 <pid>` (I think it should be rather `kill -USR1 <pid>`, perhaps it does not matter which one is used)

However, if your MongoDB runs on Windows then you have to use the `db.logRotate()` command.

Arbiters in a replica set do not replicate any data, including user/role details. This is also documented in [Replica Set Arbiter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-arbiter/#authentication):

> Because arbiters do not store data, they do not possess the internal
> table of user and role mappings used for authentication. Thus, the
> only way to log on to an arbiter with authorization active is to use
> the localhost exception.

If you want (or forced by your IT security department) to permit only authenticated access then you have to create a [Shard Local User](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/security-users/#shard-local-users) manually like this:

- Deploy your Replica Set in the normal way, see [Deploy a Replica Set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/)
- Shut down the arbiter database
- Start the arbiter in maintenance mode, see [Perform Maintenance on Replica Set Members](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/perform-maintence-on-replica-set-members/index.html)

Mainly you modify the configuration file and comment out the `replication`, `sharding` and `security` section. Modify `net.port` to prevent that any other Replica Set member connects to the database.

- Connect from local host to the arbiter database, without authentication
- Create the Shard Local Admin User.

  ```
    db.getSiblingDB("admin").createUser( {user: "admin", pwd: "secret", roles: [ "root" ] })
  ```

Instead of `root` you can also grant `[ "clusterAdmin", "userAdminAnyDatabase" ]` which is stricter.

- Shut down the arbiter database
- Restart arbiter database in normal mode.

Note, on PRIMARY/SECONDARY nodes it is sufficient to create the Shard Local User just on the primary node (after Replica Set has been initiated). It will be replicated also to secondary nodes.

Be aware, then new `mongosh` does not authenticate:

```
$ mongo 'mongodb://admin:secret@localhost:27018/admin?authSource=admin' --eval 'db.runCommand({ connectionStatus: 1 }).authInfo.authenticatedUsers'
[ { "user" : "admin", "db" : "admin" } ]


$ mongosh 'mongodb://admin:secret@localhost:28001/admin?readPreference=primaryPreferred' 
db.runCommand({ connectionStatus: 1 }).authInfo.authenticatedUsers
[]

db.getUsers()
Uncaught:
MongoServerError: command usersInfo requires authentication
```

Once I created [ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/MONGOSH-1241) for it, however it was closed due to "Works as Designed"

**Update:**

Another possibility is to use the internal membership credentials, (i.e. the keyFile) for connection. Would be one of these:

```
mongosh -u __system -p "$(tr -d '\011-\015\040' < path-to-keyfile)" --host localhost --port 27018 --authenticationDatabase local
mongosh "mongodb://__system@localhost:27018/?authSource=local" -p "$(tr -d '\011-\015\040' < path-to-keyfile)"
mongosh "mongodb://localhost:27018/?authSource=local" -u __system -p "$(tr -d '\011-\015\040' < path-to-keyfile)"
```

Or if members authenticate with x509 certificates:

```
mongosh --tlsUseSystemCA "mongodb://localhost:27018/?replicaSet=repSet&authSource=$external&authMechanism=MONGODB-X509&tls=true&tlsCertificateKeyFile=mongo.member.pem"
```

Answer (score -1):

Mongo replication seems to ignore the arbiters completely when syncing users. I use keyFile authentication in my clusters, and it always just lets me log into the arbiter without any permissions whatsoever. From the local machine, the logRotate command works (because of localhostAuthBypass). If I log in from a remote shell, I am not authorized for the command.

However, what I always do is schedule a nightly cronjob to rotate logs. You can do this as a one-liner without even logging into the mongo shell:
Simply put, it's just:

```
kill -10 $(cat <pidfile>)
00 00 * * * /usr/bin/kill -10 /mongo/mongo.pid >>/mongo/logrotation.log 2>&1
```

"-10" refers to SIGUSR1, which tells mongo to rotate the logs.
Make sure you're using the processManagement.pidFilePath (2.6) or --pidfilepath (2.4) option and that you have the same pidfilepath listed in this command.

Or if you have multiple mongos running on a server:

```
for file in /<mongo_pidfile_directory>/*.pid ; do kill -10 $(cat $file) ; done
```

Comment: currently we do not have arbiters in our replicate sets in production. your workaround is good to know because in dev where we do have arbiters i cannot do anything in the arbiter because it does not let me authenticate at all. very frustrating.

Comment: Actually the arbiter ignores **everything** (which includes users) as the arbiter does not store any data.

Comment: You can also run `for p in $(pidof mongod) ; do kill -USR1 $p; done`

Answer (score -2):

I believe the command you are looking for is db.runCommand( { logRotate : 1 } ) (run after switching to the admin database). http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/rotate-log-files/

Works fine for me on an arbiter and does rotate the log.